# How to make a child view controller understand its frame when presented in landscape?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I am presenting a child view controller from a parent view controller with the following code:

```
self.childVC = [[ChildVC alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:self.childVC];
self.childVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
self.childVC.alpha = 0.1;
[self.view addSubview:self.childVC.view];
[UIView
    animateWithDuration:0.3
    delay:0.0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
    animations:^(void) {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.childVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
];
```

The parent view controller supports all orientations. When the child is presented while the parent is in **portrait** orientation, the child's frame is as expected:

```
viewDidLoad:   <UIView: 0xeb9f70; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H;
viewDidAppear: <UIView: 0xeb9f70; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H;
```

However, when the child is presented while the parent is in **landscape** orientation, the child's frame is strange:

```
viewDidLoad:   <UIView: 0xeb9f70; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H;
viewDidAppear: <UIView: 0xeb9f70; frame = (0 0; 568 320); autoresize = W+H;
```

In viewDidLoad, the child thinks its frame is in portrait. Then it corrects itself in viewDidAppear. This sporadic changing of the frame is making the child's animation look fidgety. How can I make the frame both correct and consistent when the child is launched in landscape orientation?

Comment: What if you used `initWithFrame:`?

Comment: I didn't explicity use `initWithFrame`. The child view controller uses the default implementation of `loadView` which should have generated a `self.view` for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` represents the view in a raw state, when all elements have been loaded. Layout has not yet commenced. If your view controller is defined in a storyboard or a nib, it will have the values as they have been read from the decoder. You should not start your animation there, but in `viewWillAppear`, which should be called after view has been layout (`viewDidLayout`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations`and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`.

I found this from [ViewController Programing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1)

> On iOS 5 and earlier, a view controller can sometimes participate in the rotation process even when it isn’t the topmost full-screen view controller. This generally occurs when a container view controller asks its children for their supported interface orientations. In practice, the ability for children to override the parents is rarely useful. With that in mind, you should consider emulating the iOS 6 behavior as much as possible in an app that must also support iOS 5:
>
> In a root view controller or a view controller that is presented full screen, choose a subset of interface orientations that make sense for your user interface.
> In a child controller, support all the default resolutions by designing an adaptable view layout.

and from [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW9) you can see what happened when rotation occurred.

hope it will help you to figure it out in your situation.